# Check For Unmapped Columns In Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm writing a database synchronization tool for existing databases. One of the requirement is to validate the entities with the database schema. The program has to be aware of any database changes (like adding new columns to the database). I'm planning on using Hibernate for this project.

Is there anyway Hibernate can validate the difference between the entity and the table in the database?

Can Hibernate output SQL script so I can review the SQL script before running it to update the target database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes hibernate can output the SQL in the logs.
You need to set the  : - `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>`

but SQL generated by the server is little messy so you have to modify the column name as per your database table.

please have a look at the following XML of my project with the  hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="communityPortalPersitenceUnit">
        <class>com.googlecode.frameworksintegration.domain.Blog</class>
        <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conhint_prod" />  

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

             <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" /> 



            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!--Start :- connection pooling -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
            <!--End :- connection pooling -->


        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```